# MAX72XX with 8 digit 7 segment display library

Tags: arduino-uno

A while ago, I found a library for the MAX72XX that had functions for writing text to the display, but unfortunately cannot find such library now.

Which would be the best library to use for a text and number display? I'm using LedControl but it is very awkward to use.

Comment: Are you aware that it is not possible to represent all alphabetic characters with just 7 segments? That means that some characters cannot be printed or would be printed in a strange way.

Comment: Cosa library for Arduino has this text support for MAX72XX but this is not compatible with standard Arduino libraries as Cosa is a whole "framework" for Arduino: https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa

Comment: You might be able to just extract the library files from Cosa  https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/tree/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/LCD/Driver
and modify them.

Comment: Try this one: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/LedControl#CharSeg7Control

Answer (score 3):

I have a library for driving the MAX7219 chip connected to a 7-segment display. It is at: https://github.com/nickgammon/MAX7219

Example of use:

```C++
#include <SPI.h>
#include <bitBangedSPI.h>
#include <MAX7219.h>

const byte chips = 1;

// 1 chip, bit banged SPI on pins 6, 7, 8
MAX7219 display (chips, 6, 7, 8);  // Chips / LOAD / DIN / CLK

void setup ()
  {
  display.begin ();
  display.sendString ("HELLO");
  }  // end of setup

void loop () { }
```

In operation displaying a number:

[image: MAX7219 display]

More details at: [Interfacing LED displays with the MAX7219 driver](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11516)

Comment: Another reply of mine with no acceptance, no upvotes, and now it has been bumped by "Community" in the hope that someone will give a better answer. Good luck with that one.

Comment: Sedition! We'll be watching you.